# Cleaning/Fixing corrupted audio

Tags: audacity, sound-editing, repair, clean, fix

I've got a weird issue. I have a several hour long dialogue recording I was editing, and there's an isolated section, about 15 minutes long (pretty close to the end, but not exactly there) that I've run across where the audio is suddenly garbled.
Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTVxMQ1opMGUQE0m_zzy5tVacuA3UnhX/view

Since the audio around the section is fine and you can still hear the voices, it seems like this is a data corruption and not necessarily a sudden mic issue(it was recorded in audacity, so I don't have separate raw audio), I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to repair, or at the very least, clean up this audio, as I'd hate to lose it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to fix this. This is borked beyond repair. Sorry that won't be much help, but that's really the honest answer.